# How to compare two exact placement lists?

Tags: python, list, compare

I want to compare two lists and get the number of correct placements.
I should get `2` for output with these.

```
vp = 0

lcodecouleur = [2,2,1,1]
userinput = [1,1,1,1]

def verif_placement():
    if lcodecouleur[0] == userinput[0]:
        ++vp
    else:
        pass
    if lcodecouleur[1] == userinput[1]:
        ++vp
    else:
         pass
    if lcodecouleur[2] == userinput[2]:
        ++vp
    else:
        pass
    if lcodecouleur[3] == userinput[3]:
        ++vp
    else:
        pass
        
verif_placement()
```

Comment: `print(sum(1 for a, b in zip(lcodecouler, userinput) if a==b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both the lists to type `str`, iterate over using `zip()` and `sum()`:

```
lcodecouleur = [2,2,1,1]
userinput = [1,1,1,1]

lcodecouleur_new = [str(x) for x in lcodecouleur]
userinput_new = [str(x) for x in userinput]

print(sum([1 for a, b in zip(lcodecouleur_new, userinput_new) if b in a]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

`++vp` does nothing, do this instead:

```
vp = 0

lcodecouleur = [2, 2, 1, 1]
userinput = [1, 1, 1, 1]

def verif_placement():
    global vp
    if lcodecouleur[0] == userinput[0]:
        vp += 1
    else:
        pass
    if lcodecouleur[1] == userinput[1]:
        vp += 1
    else:
        pass
    if lcodecouleur[2] == userinput[2]:
        vp += 1
    else:
        pass
    if lcodecouleur[3] == userinput[3]:
        vp += 1
    else:
        pass

verif_placement()
```

You needed to add 1 for each match using `vp += 1` which is short for `vp = vp + 1`. You also had to define `vp` as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

One Liner Solution,Use zip() to get elements from two lists and if two nums are same then True and sum calculates True value

```
lcodecouleur = [2,2,1,1]
userinput = [1,1,1,1]
print(sum(True for i,j in zip(lcodecouleur,userinput) if i==j))
#2
```